# How do I plot a normalised graph containing two subjects

Tags: matlab, graph

I have two datas, X and Y and I would like to graph these X and Y as a function of time both starting at the same value 100 on a given time scale.

Answer (score 0):

```
plot(t,X,t,Y)
```

where t is the time interval.

Comment: I have done it another way,
```
n = 100;
normalize = @(x) x * n / x(1);
normalizedStock1 = normalize(Int);
normalizedStock2 = normalize(Mic);
```

Comment: @i9-9980XE: If you have a solution, please post it below as an answer and accept it.